# Excel está travando quando uso xlwings

Tags: python, microsoft-excel

Estou usando o python com o excel através do pacote xlwings. O problema é que o excel para de funcionar sempre que eu tento importar uma função na aba do xlwings. Eu já reiniciei o pc, mas o problema ainda continua.

Comment: Amigo, publique a pergunta em português por favor.

Comment: Edite a questão, porque se não irão marcar sua questão como fora do escopo do site.

Comment: Por favor, leia o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/75104), [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas) e [Seja mais específico na pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1481/75104)